# Serialize class keyword benefits

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

What can be the benefits of writing serialize keyword in below line of code ?

```
[Serializable]
public class Abc
{
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't know much about serialization, check [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms233843.aspx) for a start. But as the other commented, the benefit is to be able to store the state of the object (for example, to a file), and retrieve it later. If you don't need that functionality, there's no benefit at all.

Answer (score 1):

that you can transfer the object between processes? Can easily serialize them to files, streams, etc.?
There are a lot of good reasons to do this.

I do this all the time in combination with `ISerializable` this way I can implement the serialization of my objects without exposing to much or having to insert setters for immutable data.
You can even use WCF to transfer those objects but you have to make the types known or use TypeResolvers.

Just think of this as magically marking your object to be persistet or transfered.

Comment: I am using it in Object Model class library project.

Comment: I have a class library project. It has a class and contains properties for adding student data like name roll number, subjects, marks etc. I feel here that serializing the class is not useful here. Right ?

Comment: how should I know? Do you want to save a list of students to a file? If yes than this can be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

[MSDN SerializableAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serializableattribute.aspx)